# How to use @CompileStatic for pure groovy scripts in JMeter environment?

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I'd like to take advantage of `@CompileStatic` annotation in my groovy scripts in jmeter environment. It helps a lot to discover issues in compile time.

I already started to use it in my classes but I don't know how to use it in case of plain groovy scripts. For example, I have the script below and there are the `log` and `vars` variables which are kind of global variables in JMeter environment. So, eventually they will be used.

If I add the `@CompileStatic` annotation to the method below IntelliJ paints red everything and compile will fail because the compiler doesn't know what these variables are.

So, the question is how to tell the compiler in a case of a script these variables has type and what type they have, and how an instance will be provided for the script?

I apologize, I'm not a groovy expert at all.

```
void checkingInputParameters() {

    log.info("variable value:" + vars.get("some_variable_name"))
}
checkingInputParameters()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are in the wrong path, 
because [CompileStatic](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/CompileStatic.html) is a **groovy compiler** option

> let the Groovy compiler use compile time checks in the style of Java then perform static compilation, thus bypassing the Groovy meta object protocol.

JMeter (and I assume your tests in Intellij ) is using a **java compiler**

I don't think you should mix them for tests.

In JMeter use [Cache compiled](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) checkbox/feature

> checking Cache compiled script if available

Comment: I haven't mentioned that it is a groovy maven module where the JSR 233 scripts are stored. When it compiles it will be groovy. IntelliJ knows it is groovy.

Comment: @SayusiAndo eventually you want to execute it on JMeter environment,no? this will be Java code executing groovy through ScriptEngine

Comment: Yes, that is correct. But, before the groovy gets into JMeter instance and will be compiled to bytecode maven compiles it as groovy code and that is the phase where I'd like to catch all possible typo, not adding enough parameters to a function, etc issues. Like in case of a strongly typed language.

Comment: @SayusiAndo ok, to answer your question add `ApacheJMeter_core.jar` as a dependency so IntelliJ will recognize `JMeterVariables` class and `slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar` for `Logger`

Comment: It does if there is no `@CompileStatic` on the method. If there is a `@CompileStatic` annotation on the method every occasion of them is marked as error. Everything is red meaning difficult to determine which red mark is error which is not.